# How do I add password to postgresql peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I want to connect to a postgresql server with peewee but I keep getting a error that I need a password but I have no clue how to add it current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
.I have read every bit of the docs and still have no clue how. If I can't help i'll just go to sqlite.

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import json
from peewee import *
"""Setting up variables"""
db = PostgresqlDatabase("Tweets",user='postgres')
Cred_Filename = 'Keys.json'
jf = open(Cred_Filename)
creds = json.load(jf)
jf.close()
twitter = Twython(creds['consumer_key'],
                  creds['consumer_secret'],
                  creds['access_token'],
                  creds['access_token_secret'])

"""End of variables"""


"""PostgreSql Setup"""
class BaseModel(Model):
    """A base model that will use our Postgresql database"""
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    tweet = CharField()
try:
    Tweet.create_table()
except Exception as e:
    pass
"""End of PostgreSql Setup"""

"""Pulling Tweets and displaying them"""
def PullTweet():
    """Take user input and pull and print 10 newest tweets"""
    user_input = input('Please Enter A Username: ')
    try:
       user_timeline = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name=user_input)
   except TwythonError as e:
       print(e)
    print(user_input)
    for tweets in user_timeline:
        print('[*]' + tweets['text'])
        try:
            tweet = Tweet(tweet=tweets['text'])
            tweet.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
PullTweet()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`PostgresqlDatabase`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#using-postgresql) just passes additional `kwargs` through to [`psycopg2.connect`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect), and that signature looks like

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", user="postgres", password="secret")
```

So you just need to add a `password` kwarg to your call:

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase("Tweets",user='postgres', password='***')
```

Note, though, that it's generally not safe to store your database password in plain text within your program.

Comment: When I add the password is when i get the commands ignored until end of transaction.

Comment: what is the exception or output you get?

Comment: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block